# how to define foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql

I have three mysql tables. Tables are already created.

```
Requests -  request_id, request_message, user_id
Responses - response_id, response_message, user_id
users -     user_id, user_name
```

Now i want to define foreign key constraints on that, such that

```
1. If user_id is not present in Users table, and someone is inserting the data in Requests or Responses for that user_id -- then error
2. If request_id is not present in Requests table, then if someone is inserting in responses table for that request_id -- then error 

3. If someone deletes an user_id, all associated requests and responses with that user_id should be deleted automatically.
4. If someone deletes an request_id, all the associated responses with it, should be deleted automatically.
```

If i am missing any thing please let me know.

How to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Devesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full sql to create your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reponses` (
  `response_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `response_message` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`response_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_reponses_users1` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requests` (
  `request_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `request_message` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`request_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_requests_users` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


ALTER TABLE `reponses`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reponses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `requests`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `requests_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Option that allows you to delete records related to user is `ON DELETE CASCADE`. By default MySql sets `NO ACTION` which refers to `RESTRICT` and doesn't allow parent record to be deleted while it has related objects. I think that you didn't mention the relation between responses and requests but you should get the idea ;).